# Publish in a repo to a specific branch with GitHub Api

Tags: github, github-api

I'm creating a iOS workflow to publish notes on my repo, it is [working quite well](https://github.com/ramiro-ruiz/ramiroruiz.com/tree/master/content/notes) but now I want to do it on a branch to keep testing.

I'm exporting the note text and pass the next url:

https://api.github.com/repos/ramiro-ruiz/ramiroruiz.com/contents/content/notes/slug.md

Send the authorization token and a simple commit message.

All this is done [on master](https://github.com/ramiro-ruiz/ramiroruiz.com/commits/master/content/notes) and to send it to a branch I tried by adding `?ref=my-branch` at the end of the url (https://api.github.com/repos/ramiro-ruiz/ramiroruiz.com/contents/content/notes/slug.md?ref=my-branch) but is not working as it keeps publishing to master.

Anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [create or update content API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents#create-or-update-file-contents=) does include a `branch` parameters, not a `ref` one.

```
PUT /repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path
```

`branch`: The branch name.
Default: the repository’s default branch (usually `master` or now `main`)

Example:

```bash
curl \
  -X PUT \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/contents/PATH \
  -d '{"branch":"sample","message":"my commit message","committer":{"name":"Monalisa Octocat","email":"octocat@github.com"},"content":"bXkgbmV3IGZpbGUgY29udGVudHM="}'
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I was thinking that the branch should be in the url, this worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Can you help me here. I am trying to do the same thing but the changes are all being made to the master branch. `https://api.github.com/repos/shashank-crypto/BlogAPI/contents/new.js?branch=sample` and in params i am giving `message` and `content`

Comment: @ShashankChaudhary I have edited the answer to include an example using `curl`. I have highlighted the `branch` parameter.

Comment: Thank you, I have been looking for this answer for past 7 or so hours.